# What is the problem for PTHREAD_CANCELED and thread’s start function return value

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads, pthread-join

I'm reading [Kerrisk's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004OEJMZM) and see that the following as a note,

> **Caution is required when using a cast integer as the return value of a thread’s start function.** The reason for this is that
>   `PTHREAD_CANCELED`, the value returned when a thread is canceled (see
>   Chapter 32), is usually some implementation-defined integer value cast
>   to `void *`. If a thread’s start function returns the same integer
>   value, then, to another thread that is doing a `pthread_join()`, it
>   will wrongly appear that the thread was canceled. In an application
>   that employs thread cancellation and chooses to return cast integer
>   values from a thread’s start functions, we must ensure that a normally
>   terminating thread does not return an integer whose value matches
>   `PTHREAD_CANCELED` on that Pthreads implementation. **A portable
>   application would need to ensure that normally terminating threads
>   don’t return integer values that match `PTHREAD_CANCELED` on any of
>   the implementations on which the application is to run.**

I don't understand importance of the note. Could you codify(show its simple code snippet) it simply to illustrate? What is the issue in th(ese)is case(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical definition of `PTHREAD_CANCELED` (quoted verbatim from `/usr/include/pthread.h` on the machine where I'm typing this, which runs Linux with GNU libc):

```
#define PTHREAD_CANCELED ((void *) -1)
```

So if you have code like this to check for cancellation:

```
void *thread_result;
int rv = pthread_join(child, &thread_result);
if (rv)
    error_exit("pthread_join failed", rv);
if (thread_result == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
    error_exit("thread canceled", 0);
```

you must not also have a thread procedure like this:

```
static void *appears_to_be_canceled(void *unused)
{
    return ((void *) -1);
}
```

because `PTHREAD_CANCELED` and `((void *) -1)` are equal.  Note that the number  is not guaranteed to be −1, it could differ from system to system, and there's no good way to find out what it is at compile time because `((void *)...)` isn't usable in an `#if` expression.

There are two good ways to avoid this problem:

- Don't use thread cancellation, so you don't have to check for `PTHREAD_CANCELED` and don't have to care what its numeric value is.  This is a good idea for several other reasons, most importantly that cancellation makes it even harder to write robust multithreaded code than it already is.
- Return only valid pointers from your thread procedures, not numbers.  A good idiom to follow is like this:

  ```
  struct worker_data
  {
     // put _everything_ your thread needs to access in here
  };
  static void *worker_proc (void *data_)
  {
     struct worker_data *data = data_;
     // do stuff with `data` here 
     return data_;
  }
  ```

  Returning the `worker_data` object means the code that calls `pthread_join` doesn't have to track which `worker_data` object corresponds to which `pthread_t`.  And it also means the return value of a successfully completed thread is guaranteed not to be equal to `PTHREAD_CANCELED`, because `PTHREAD_CANCELED` is guaranteed not to compare equal to any valid pointer.

Comment: Having read the part of the book addressing  _Thread Cancellation(Chapter 32)_, I now grasp it better. Thanks.